# update only one field using viewmodel in httpPost form <edited>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

this  code  suppose to update only one value in a table and keep all the other value as is .

how ever I cant find out why , the db.SaveChanges doesn't save it . in the debugger I can see that the value has change ,

this is my code

```
 if (model.rev.GBU == "Good")
                 {
                     //This section will do:---- 1> get subjectId -- 2> Update  only in the subjectid  good rank
                     //Update this subjectid   (int)good +1  data 
                    model.sub.SubjectId = R_getvelue.SubjectId;


                     //get the relevant value from the Db
                     var Good = R_getvelue.Good;
                     int iGoodRating = Convert.ToInt32(Good);
                     //Add 1 (one )to the value in the Db
                     iGoodRating++;
                     model.sub.Good = iGoodRating;
                     //Keep All the existing data in the other fields 
                     UpdateModel(model.sub);
                     // db.Entry(model.sub).State = EntityState.Modified; >removing all values biside "Good

                }

             await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("index");
         }

        ViewBag.OccupationId = new SelectList(db.occupation, "OccupationId", "OccupationDecription", model.Occupation);
         return View(model);
     }
```

Comment: Where is your `db.SaveChanges()` call?

Comment: the code is very long but it it call at the end , do you think I should submit all the code ?

Comment: "Should I submit all the code" - no - there's already *far too much* irrelevant code.   Please read this: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Danny, quite on the contrary, I think you should simplify your example. Right now it is very difficult to see what part of the code you have submitted is actually relevant to your question.

Comment: Ok. I have updated the code and "Sharpened" the Q.